# Can you write line by line to a PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a script that generates Javascript based on user form inputs. At present the code is outputted to a txt file on the server, but I'd like to put it into a MySql database.

Writing line by line to a txt file is easy with fopen, and helpful with my script due to the way the code is generated and wrapped around user inputs (various loops etc).

However, I'd really like to write the output to a variable, and then send that to the database. However, I can't see any way of accomplishing this?

Im sure it is possible, but the information I've found online only deals with quite basic variable creation.

A dirty solution would be to write to the txt file as I currently do, and then load the text file into a variable and then delete the text file. But this seems silly and clearly a waste of processing time.

Very new to Php so sorry if the above seems dumb.

Comment: What you need to do is submit the form with ajax into php

Comment: You want to retrieve each line of a text (from a variable) and write into a database, don't you?

Comment: Have you looked into [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)?

Comment: Could you just write each line to the variables by concatenating the variable to the new line. I haven't written PHP in a couple of years, but I think something like  `$var.="\n".$dataline`  would work for each new line created which would load up `$var` with the whole enchilada that can then be sent to the database.

Comment: rtm: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

It's not too difficult, you can declare the variable with the first line and then incrementally write to it, with the `\n` escape sequence (representing a new line) separating each line. You can size use the `PHP_EOL` built-in  inserted, as commented. The=` assignment operator appends the string following the operator to the variable's value prior to the operation.

```
$lines = "my first line";
while (condition) {
    $lines .= PHP_EOL . "my next line";
}
```

---

A derivative way of doing this would be to insert all the lines inside the loop and start with just declaring an empty string.

```
$lines = "";
while (condition) {
    $lines .= "my next line" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note that this method will add an empty newline at the end, which you can trim off of needed.

---

Alternatively, another way would be to create an array, push to it, and then use the `implode` function to glue together the array into a string using a newline.

```
$lines = array();
while (condition) {
    array_push($lines, "my next line");
}
$lines = implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
```

Comment: Or `PHP_EOL` for better interoperability.

Comment: Thanks @lawrence-cherone, edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play around with this.